# Can Ultisnips regular expression match forward?

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips

The question may be also phrased as, can Ultisnips regular expression match after the current cursor?

My goal is to have a postfix of curly bracket for LaTeX subscripts. Say I want to type `a_{bcd}`, but in the first place I typed `a_c`. I wish I could move my cursor in the following position (cursor represented by |) `a_|c`, and insert a curly bracket. In the end what I get is `a_{$1c$2}$0`.

What appears intuitive for me is the following

```
snippet "_{([^\s$]*)" "subscript" iA
_{$1 `!p match.group(1)`$2}$0
endsnippet
```

however it does not work, and it seems that Ultisnips does not match the text after the cursor.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You *may* have better luck with the plugin maintainers.

Comment: Can you share an example of the snippet definition you're using? It seems you're using a snippet with autotrigger (`A` option), is that the case?

Comment: Hi, filbranden. Yes I am using the `A` option. I updated with my code that does not work.